# Getting "This item is currently being modified" when testing purchases on iPad

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have an app with many in-app purchases.
Two days ago we started getting the following error message when testing purchases:
"This item is currently being modified. Please try again later" and then the purchase fails.
This happens 90% of the time.

We thought there was something wrong with the test user we were using. But using another user account also produces the same issue.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: same here! but just with one product. I am able to purchase other products :S

Comment: same here. We suspect it is an Israeli app-store thing. Non Israeli app-store accounts can successfully purchase from our app. Us in .il can't.

Comment: @Variant you are probably right. We don't see this affecting our users, who are mostly from the US and other countries.

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered the same error on all of my IAP (I'm in the UK). According to this link, the consensus is that it's caused by Apple changing their pricing tiers:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31363

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but reconnecting(logout, then login) to appstore with my account solved it.

Comment: I had this issue on iOS 14.8, there were no restore from backup in the past year. I switch to another Apple ID which was not US and then it got messed up. Logout out and loging in again solved it.

Answer (score 0):

this issue can happen if you restored from a backup via iCloud and the device thinks it is still restoring from the backup

go to settings/tap your name/icloud/icloud backup/ stop the restore and the message will go away.

Answer (score -1):

It's been happening to me with several e-magazines, either subscriptions or single issues. Oddly enough, one of them ("Word among us") I could subscribe for 1 month, but not for 1 year - keep getting a "This item..." message.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the help center to see how to [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) the questions. If you are facing the same problem as the question, add it as a comment.